# Script explanation needed

Tags: terminal, sh

I found the following script from someone else's project.

Can someone please explain what the below script does?

```
for libtocopy in $LIBS_TO_COPY ; do 
    libfile=`ldd bin/foo.so | grep lib${libtocopy} | cut -d' ' -f 3`
    if [ "x$libfile" != "x" ] ; then 
        #echo "$libtocopy : copying $libfile in libs"
        cp $libfile foo/libs 
    fi
    done
```

Comment: I will offer a bounty for anyone who explains the script line by line.

Comment: you'd need to actually put up the bounty for that to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short the script will extract a selection of dynamically resolved shared libraries from the `bin/foo.so` binary mentioned in the script.

The command driving the whole script there is [ldd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html).  This will resolve and print any dymanic dependencies for an executable.

E.g. this is an example output (on a Raspberry Pi that was handy, but the output is compatible):

```
ldd /bin/grep
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7ef36000)
        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76f8b000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre.so.3 (0x76efe000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0x76eeb000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x76dac000)
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76fa1000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x76d83000)
```

So for each of the names in the LIBS_TO_COPY variable, (e.g. `pthread` on the last line above), it will find the line with a `lib` prefix (e.g. `libpthread`).

Each of these matching lines is piped into `cut`, which will pick out the third field in the line (using space as the delimiter) - i.e. the resolved path to that library.

Then those resolved dependencies are copied to the selected directory.

For example, with the `echo` in the script uncommented, and `bin/foo.so` switched to `/bin/grep`:

```
$ export LIBS_TO_COPY='pthread c dl'
$ bash libextract.bash
pthread : copying /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 in libs
c : copying /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 in libs
dl : copying /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 in libs
```

(Both the `bash` and `sh` shells give the same output).